# Load Json data from file into Parse.com backend via Rest API

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest, parse-platform

Evening folks,

I am attempting to load data from a .json file into parse.com backend.  I can get the rest api to load manually added json as per the example provided from Parse.com from the terminal on my Mac:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: removed" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: removed" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Test
```

This works fine.

How can I read a saved .Json file with only these three parameters(Json is validated fine) and send the data to my Parse backend?
"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false

I believe I have the option to use PHP/Jquery etc. however I have not used any of these languages extensively and a quick code example would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Gerard

Comment: You can try `curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: removed" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: removed" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @file.json https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Test`

Comment: Hi Prashant, thanks for the answer, this curl just adds one row to the Parse class with it empty, I'm going to have a quick look at your PHP solution.  If the file is set as -d @file.json it should parse and add each result from the code above right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pure `PHP` solution:

```
$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Test';
$fields_string = file_get_contents('file.json');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
/* End of first request */
```